# Azure Kubernetes Services Always placing pod on Virtual ACI node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I have a kubernetes cluster with a single node (in test for now) in Azure Kubernetes Services but with virtual nodes enabled. I'd like nodes to be primarily placed on the physical nodes with bursts onto the virtual ACI nodes when needed.

I'm using Keda to scale up the nodes based on a queue's size.

When I configure it as I've seen in online like this

```
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: type
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - virtual-kubelet
      tolerations:
        - key: virtual-kubelet.io/provider
          operator: Equal
          effect: NoSchedule
```

the scheduler seems to ignore the preferred scheduling and always puts the pod on the virtual-kubelet mode.

I don't know if I'm just missing something or what. It's been very frustrating. My work loads are small enough now I can serve everything on one node just fine in test but I'd like to be able to upscale into ACI when needed.

Comment: what about scheduler logs, they should give you an idea why workloads are not scheduled onto yor single node (btw single node cluster is pretty much useless)

Comment: I'll check the scheduler logs. I know that a single node cluster is almost useless, this is just a test cluster, I don't want to pay for more than one server. With the auto scaling into ACI I hoping to save some costs and get scale up when needed.

Comment: Hello, i have the same problem. Have you found a solution?